# Get all image from single page using this query

Tags: query, attachments

I'm having some trouble with this sample widget code. I want to get all images (Minus the post thumbnail) from a page called "Gallery" but for some reason this is pulling all uploaded images from the entire site.

Also, how would I go about excluding the post thumbnail from this query?

```
  query_posts('pagename=gallery');
if (have_posts()) : 
echo "<ul class='recentwidget group photowidget'>";
while (have_posts()) : the_post();
    $args = array(
    'post_type' => 'attachment',
    'numberposts' => 1,
    'post_status' => null,
    'post_parent' => $post->ID
);

$attachments = get_posts( $args );
    if ( $attachments ) {
    foreach ( $attachments as $attachment ) {
       echo '<li class="left imageshadow photolarge">';
       echo wp_get_attachment_image( $attachment->ID, 'full' );
       echo '</li>';
      }
    }
endwhile;

endif; 
wp_reset_query();
```

Comment: Apparently the use of `query_posts` is not without [drawbacks](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/query_posts#Caveats). Have you tried using [`get_posts`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_posts) instead? But then, I think using The Loop at all in this case is overkill. Just hardcode the page ID into your call to `get_posts` (which is currently inside The Loop).

Comment: Unfortunately my client is a fan of query_posts (Something to do with them being able to edit it later on should they need to). Is there no way to do it using query_posts ?

Comment: No, sorry. I have not really done something like this myself, and from skimming the Codex your code looks reasonable to me (besides coding style *cough*). Oh, it is contract work. In that case you probably want to wrap your feature into a smallish plugin with an options page so they can't break it (and you can reuse it). Maybe even use an [existing plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/gallery-widget/)?

Comment: see this faq: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1753/when-should-you-use-wp-query-vs-query-posts-vs-get-posts

Comment: also, i would recommend you to use WP_query if you are creating secondary loops for example in widgets. but if you must use query_posts function to alter the main loop, remember to add pagination to the query_posts argument list.
http://scribu.net/wordpress/wp-pagenavi/right-way-to-use-query_posts.html

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### Use get_children

I used this code to extract all the images from a page gallery in the chosen order. you can include this code in the loop or use it stand alone. just choose the appropriate post_parent code (see bellow the code example).

This example show all images associated to the page id 1, have a look:

```
        $images = get_children( array( 'post_parent' => 1, 'post_type' => 'attachment', 'post_mime_type' => 'image', 'orderby' => 'menu_order', 'order' => 'ASC', 'numberposts' => 999 ) ); 
/* $images is now a object that contains all images (related to post id 1) and their information ordered like the gallery interface. */
        if ( $images ) { 

                //looping through the images
                foreach ( $images as $attachment_id => $attachment ) {
                ?>

                            <?php /* Outputs the image like this: <img src="" alt="" title="" width="" height="" /> */  ?> 
                            <?php echo wp_get_attachment_image( $attachment_id, 'full' ); ?>

                            This is the Caption:<br/>
                            <?php echo $attachment->post_excerpt; ?>

                            This is the Description:<br/>
                            <?php echo $attachment->post_content; ?>

                <?php
                }
        }
```

Find the post id you wan to extract images from and insert it into this argument:
 `'post_parent' => 1` (replace the 1 with your page id)

you can also use:

```
'post_parent' => $post->ID
```

If you want to use get_children in a loop, and get the post id from the returned post id.

If you want to exclude the image selected as a featured image i would have a `if` statement check if the image URL is equal to the featured image URL.

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: This worked perfectly. Although, is there a way to change the output of the image? For example, adding a specific class to them?

Comment: Nice to be helpfull :) if you add this array into the list of arguments for the function wp_get_attachment_image like this: 

wp_get_attachment_image($attachment_id, 'full', array('class' => "your-calss" ));

 I believe you get the desired effekt, havent tried though.

Comment: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_attachment_image  <-- see this codex page for more info :)

Comment: Thanks for that. In the end I just wrapped the image output into a list and I got the desired effect.

Comment: It worked for me when I replaced `'post_parent' => 1` with `'post_parent' => get_the_ID()`

Answer (score -1):

Easiest way is to use `get_attached_media()`. There are many different ways, almost all of them covered [here](https://barisatasoy.org/wordpress-and-image-management-2-getting-all-images-in-a-post/)

Comment: Please [edit] your answer and at least add a brief of all the ways and then share the link. A link-only answer will become irrelevant when the link comes dead.